# highlight/ navigate line number in visual svn through url

Tags: git, svn, github, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I have an svn repository, and have java files in it. I can access files in the repository through url in web browser. e.g.

> https://serverName/svn/repositoryName/file1.java

This java file has 100 lines. Is there a way I can navigate to any line number/ highlight any line number in this file through the url?

In git, there is option to highlight a line number if I pass the line number parameter in git url. i.e.

> https://servername/git/repository/file1.java**#L45**

will show file1.java in the browser and also highlight line number 45 of file1.java.

I am looking for similar feature in svn to highlight a particular line number. As of now I am using visual SVN server manager to manage all SVN activities on server.

Answer (score 0):

I am glad to tell you that we've released VisualSVN Server 4.0.0. You can now add links to line numbers and highlight lines of code. Please, see the [Release Notes](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/4.0/) and the [changelog](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/) for more information.

[image]

You can [try this feature on the demo server](https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#asf/view/r1859367/serf/trunk/serf.h?line=68). You can download VisualSVN Server 4.0.0 for free from the [main download page](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/) (no registration required!).